# Can't Find BreezeJS's entityErrors Collection

Tags: javascript, typescript, breeze

I am working on getting CORS setup for my service, and when I run locally it all works fine, but when I run against my server, I get the following error when I make a breeze metadata call:

> Metadata query failed for: https://MyServer.MyDomain.net/MyApp/breeze/MyController/Metadata; Server side errors encountered - see the entityErrors collection on this object for more detail

I get this error from the following setup:

```
getOrder(orderId: number): void {
    var query = new breeze.EntityQuery('Orders');  
    this.entityManager.executeQuery(query)
        .then(this.querySucceeded)
        .catch(this.queryFailed);
}


queryFailed(error: any) {
    alert('failed for ' + );
}
```

The `error` object that is passed into my `queryFailed` method does not have an 'entityErrors' collection on it.  I also checked `this.entityManager` for an `entityErrors` property and could not find it.

**Where can I find this this `entityErrors` collection?**

Answer (score 0):

That's an incorrect error message in this case.  You cannot get an entityErrors collection returned from a metadata call.  Inspect the other properties of the `error` object in your `queryFailed` method to see what is going wrong.